# Linq join selects to much data

Tags: c#, linq

The problem is in my database i have a person object which has a child object which contains 2 instances of the history of that person. Now when selecting the person object from the database it returns 2 instances of the given person with each different record of the history of the person.

My LINQ select

```
var list = from person in Context.People
           join pinfoHist in Context.PersonInfoHistories on person.Id equals pinfoHist.PersonId into ph from p_info_hist in ph.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select person;
```

Does anyone know why it does that and is there a way around that ?

Comment: Do you need history data of the person? If yes, which history record?

Comment: Why are you using `into ph from p_info_hist in ph.DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Comment: yeah i just realized that isn't the way to go :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about a fact that you have 2 rows with the start (person) information the same, you can do 2 different, distinct requests to get data:

One to get list of persons, another the list of history of all of them. After create a relationship between these 2 data tables in memory.

The issue here is that your *data* is structured in that way. If the person record by itself is not so big, I would keep in the way you already doing:

you have a list of data and on every row you have a person with it's address.